# Load log4j.properties with JAR

Tags: java, jar, log4j

I have a jar file with the following Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Created-By: 1.7.0_07 (Oracle Corporation)  
Main-Class: test.Main  
Class-Path: ./log4j.properties lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

I run the class as follows

```
java -jar test.jar
```

And this is my folder

```
lib
log4j.properties
test.jar
```

Why I can't see the log4j properties file? This is what I see

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (test.Main).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Thank you

SOLUTION:
changed my classhpath in the MANIFEST to this

```
Class-Path: . lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897528/problems-to-put-log4-properties-classpath

Answer (score 18):

You can also start your JVM with argument:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:"./your/properties/path/log4j.properties"
```

to specify arbitrary location of your external log properties. I used this a lot in one particular project.

Comment: `log4j.configuration` is for xml config

Comment: Well my friend, it works just fine with the properties file. Try it and see.

Comment: The jar versions used: log4j-1.2.14, slf4j-api-1.5.8, slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8

Comment: Sorry, my fault. They have single property for both xml and properties configs. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_Procedure

Answer (score 11):

Properties file doesn' go in classpath, you must provide it and call it from code as shown [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2008/07/baisc-steps-to-configure-log4j-using-xml-and-properties-file/).

EDIT:
With your directory structure you call it like this:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

EDIT2:

Also, you must provide appender for it:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender1
log4j.logger.[logger-name]=level, Appender1
log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

If you want finer control over logging, remove the first line (root looger) and put the second one where instead of [logger-name] you put the topmost package so that all the classes inside that package can use logging.

You can define multiple appenders and assign them to different classes in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

`PropertyConfigurator.configure(ABC.class.getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"))` worked me correctly, but basically you need to place Log4j properties file in Source Code folder (next to Java Class).

OR you can try putting outside and give proper path in `getResourceAsStream("resources/log4j.properties")` method

Comment: just this resolved my issue. TNX A LOT