# How to set my log4j.properties to my classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

This could be a duplicate, so please bear with me.
I have a `log4j.properties` file in `\WebContent\conf` folder.
I don't know if it is set in the classpath or not.

I am using `Spring Source Tool Suite` for development.
Can anyone please help me set it to the classpath?

Comment: Open a `.classpath` file from your project to check which `classpathentry`s exist in it (namely, is this folder specified). If you don't find the other way, I think that you can even edit it manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897528/problems-to-put-log4-properties-classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `\WebContent\conf`? `WebContent` is the "web" folder of a dynamic web project in Eclipse? Then place the config file directly there.

If you don't put your log4j config in a root folder that is part of the classpath you can use

> -Dlog4j.configuration=name-and-path-of-config-file

when you start the JVM.