# Log4j 1.2.17 Jar not found

Tags: java, apache, jboss, log4j

I am deploying my application as a JAR on JBoss EAP 6.2 and trying to implement apache log4j 1.2.17.

In my program i have:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
...
Logger newLogger = Logger.getLogger(name);
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties path");
return  newLogger;
```

However, every time I try to run through this I always get a stack trace with this caused by:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
at "the program I am in"...
```

The log4j.jar file is defined within my classpath of my project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Matt

Comment: Please describe the structure of your ear.

Comment: I am not using an EAR I am using a JAR to deploy my application.
I have the root project which contains the src. The src contains the program that I have my logging code in as well as a META-INF folder which contains my jboss-deployment-structure.xml and MANIFEST.MF

The .classpath is within the root project and contains the log4j.jar.

Comment: Then how do you put log4j into the class path? Did you define the dependency in the MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: Yes I did. My MANIFEST.MF looks like this:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.apache.log4j

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897528/problems-to-put-log4-properties-classpath

Comment: Tried this. Got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my jboss-deployment-structure.xml I had added the

```
<exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
```

like it said to in the migration manual however this seemed to be my problem. Removing this allowed my program to find the jar file.