# log4j likes its properties in a jar file?

Tags: java, properties, log4j, executable-jar

I have a Java application which I'm executing on Linux direct from an executable jar file

```
java -cp .:./lib -Duser.timezone=GMT -Dlog4j.debug -jar programName.jar
```

The program uses a number of other jar files which are all in one directory and 4 properties files all of which are in another directory (the current directory). Both directories are included in the `CLASSPATH`.

Simple enough right.

It would be, except that Log4j fails to find `log4j.properties`. The only way I have managed to make it find `log4j.properties` is to include it in `programName.jar`

This is not what I want, I want to have it using `log4j.properties` residing in the same directory as all the other properties files, they are in the `CLASSPATH` and are found as you would expect.

The other jar files being used are:

- `jdom-2.0.5.jar`
- `log4j-1.2.17.jar`
- `ojdbc7.jar`
- `quartz-2.2.1.jar`
- `slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar`
- `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar`

I'm wondering if `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar` does some configuration which prevents log4j from scanning the `CLASSPATH` when looking for the properties file. My code does not include any instructions which aim to specify the location of the properties file.

I've not yet tried executing the program without the `-jar` option, I will try that next.

Does this ring any bells so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Add an argument to jvm (`log4j.configuration`). e.g.:

```
java -cp .:./lib -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -Duser.timezone=GMT ...
```

You may want to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063017/870248) for more options.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I do not understand your reasoning. My log4j.properties is custom only in the sense of what it contains. Its name and location are standard. Please could you elaborate explaining why I need to specify the name when I'm using the standard (non xml) name.

Comment: Hello Paul, thank you, your suggestion did help, it got me going. Sadly I am left frustrated not knowing why Log4j is failing to find log4j.properties even though it's in the CLASSPATH.